# content disappearing minutes after it's published

Tags: database, content, cache

I'm with a very serious problem.

Some information disappears after being published. Not exactly at the moment, but it shows up for a few minutes and then disappears.

**This does not happen with titles or content**, only with custom fields, menus and images (maybe others, but this is what I could identify so far). I'm using ACF PRO, but deactivating it does nothing to solve the issue

The images are cached by Jetpack, so on that side the site works for the moment, but the rest I have no idea why it can be. One thing with images: they show up in media library for 20 or 30 minutes, maybe one hour. After that, they turn into the default grey icon and are gone away. Also, images have their post_thumbnail sizes created. However, on many images the original image isn't uploaded to `wp-content`, just the thumbnail sizes. This behavior is not consistent: sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't happen.

I already tried activating / deactivating themes and plugins and nothing. Obviously I deactivated cache. I added `max_vars` to 10000, nothing (however, I did this in `wp-config.php`, I can't edit `htaccess` at all).

I'm almost sure it's something from the database, or from the server because it's like there's a kind of giant cache that disappears. There was a person working but he disappeared from the face of the earth and now I do not know what to do.

For what it's worth: I can not edit the `htaccess` file, whatever I do it gives me 500 error. But I can generate it from Permalinks

Comment: I'd suggest hiring a new developer, short of posting your entire codebase in your question there isn't enough information to diagnose the problem, and it'll need some in depth debugging, not the kind you're likely to find for free

Answer (score 1):

It is true that this problem will need some extensive (and knowledgable) hands-on to fix.

In general, though, I would

- disable all caching, including any that JetPack does
- use my hosting File access (or FTP) to edit/change htaccess
- change all credentials - WordPress, hosting, FTP, databases - resetting all passwords to different (and strong)
- reinstalling (manually) WordPress (from the admin/updates), updating everything else (themes/plugins)
- using FTP (or hosting file manager) look at all folders for unknown files (sort by date to find files that 'stick out' because they are different). Do this after you change credentials

All of this will take time (and some expertise), so if you are not comfortable doing it yourself, then find a competent WP guru.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Rick. I already did everything you mention to no avail. I have some knowledge, not an expert but not a newbie either. For what I can say (not 100% sure) problems started with some DB or server work a *disappeared* sys-admin did. I understand this is quite a massive issue, but I'm looking for some general guidance on where to look without breaking the site (it's alive and 7000+ posts and 30000+ images, so can't play with that)

Comment: My first place to look would be the theme and any associated functions therein, and would look for code that was suspicious. Second look would be all plugins, especially those that haven't been updated by plugin author lately. Even then, perhaps reinstalling plugin code (from WP repository) would be useful. I'd also look at generated page code (several pages) for anything unusual. Maybe would be useful to export site content/pix into local site (or a new WP install in a new folder on your host) and see how that behaves. (More)

Comment: Maybe create a new post, then look in database for that post (via host phpMyAdmin). Make note of that records field's content, then check for that record after the post goes wonky. And maybe install security plugin that would keep track of all changes made (like WP Security Log). And look at error logs (in root and wp-admin folder) for hints. This may require deep-diving by a WP geek; I can only give general answers; I'd (or others) have to deep-dive on a contract basis.